# Android Wear: implementation of standard Timer App

Tags: wear-os

I'm trying to implement the same app as standard Timer app (for learning purposes).

1. Is it available sources of standard Timer app installed on Android Wear?
2. How to implement starting and displaying Activity from Sleeping Mode. Like green screen in Timer app, that appears when timer reach zero. (the problem: flags `FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON`, `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON`, `FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` and `FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD` in onCreate method don't help to cancel Sleep Mode Screen and display target Activity to user).

Cheers!

Comment: @Umair, yep, I found solution, will provide answer as soon as I will be sure that it's 100% working (need to test in detail).

Comment: may be I can lessen your work and test it for you :d 

struggling with similar issue, need to generate a notification (with embedded intent) from sleep mode.

Comment: Don't you think that we have to implement Timer on Handheld & Notify Wearable whenever required? Moreover it will save some battery also.

Comment: @Vintesh it's not good UX, because it most cases user can go away from phone while don't want to skip timer alarm.

Comment: I second Umair's question. Do you have any solution that may work?

Comment: Guys, check out the sources — https://github.com/AlexKorovyansky/WearPomodoro, it's the same mechanic as in standard timer.

Comment: Awesome. So I guess the relevant part is that you've put `WakeLock` stuff in the `BoradcastReceiver` rather than the activity? At least that worked for me. Thanks!